# Which out of the two code fragments would be better to implement for a comparator?

Tags: java

I wanted to know what would be the best way to implement the comparator method following best practice?

I implemented one and someone else implemented the other.

Please any advice on which is more suitable would be great!

```
public class Product
{
public Product (String name, int weight) {

        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight; 

    }

    public static final Comparator<Product> BY_WEIGHT = new Comparator<Product>() {

        public int compare(final Product weight1, final Product weight2) {

            return weight1.weight - weight2.weight;
        }
    };

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
}
```

or

```
public class Product {

    private final String name;
    private final int weight;

    public Product (String name, int weight) {

        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight; 

    }

    public static final Comparator<Product> BY_WEIGHT = new Comparator<Product>(){

        public int compare (final Product p1, final Product p2) {

            return Integer.compare(p1.getWeight(), p2.getWeight());
        }

    };

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The `return weight1.weight - weight2.weight` implementation has a risk of numeric overflow, so it might misbehave for some inputs (though it's probably safe to assume a `Product`'s weight doesn't go anywhere near `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, so that implementation will probably work fine) .

In general `Integer.compare(p1.getWeight(), p2.getWeight())` is the better implementation, since it can't overflow (it returns `(x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1)`).

Comment: @Glains yep, the second implementation also has better naming.

Answer (score 0):

The second option, for reason already mentioned by @Eran.

This version uses built-in comparator:

```
    public static final Comparator<Product> BY_WEIGHT =
            Comparator.comparingInt(Product::getWeight);
```